# JSON parse error SCRIPT 1014 INVALID CHARACTER

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am experiencing some issues when trying to call in and parse some JSON. The error I am receiving is **SCRIPT1014: Invalid Character** this issue is happening universally across all browsers not just internet explorer.

Jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "enquiries.php?show=all",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
        console.log(obj);
    }
});
```

Output JSON:

```
{"0":{"ID":"1","first_name":"test","last_name":"test","email_address":"test","daytime_tel":"34343434","mobile_tel":"343434","comments":"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf","location_url":"32423452322resdfsdfxdf","date_of_submit":"2013-05-30","time_of_submit":null,"marked_as_read":"0","sender":"test test"}}
```

I have checked this as valid JSON using JSONLint:

```
{
"0": {
    "ID": "1",
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "test",
    "email_address": "test",
    "daytime_tel": "34343434",
    "mobile_tel": "343434",
    "comments": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf",
    "location_url": "32423452322resdfsdfxdf",
    "date_of_submit": "2013-05-30",
    "time_of_submit": null,
    "marked_as_read": "0",
    "sender": "test test"
}
```

}

I have also tried including a separate file to print the JSON (instead of the enquiries.php?view=all method) same problem persists.

Comment: You already have `dataType: "json"`, why parse?

Comment: I think it might actually be @MichaelRamirez, because if it is an object already, feeding it to JSON.parse would require calling its toString method, and that will result in something like `[object Object]` (may vary by browser).

Comment: I was referring to the answer 'likely enquiries.php is not in UTF 8' above @CBroe - I didn't realise I even had dataType in.

Comment: Ah, OK. (People should really have the guts to leave their comments in place even if they were not correct – that would avoid such confusion …)

Comment: @CBroe - Not a question of guts. Wrong comments only add noise.

Answer (score 1):

As @Malti and @CBroe pointed out above the problem was to do with dataType: 'json' - issue resolved.

Comment: Removing that is not the best solution. Just let jQuery parse the response for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to parse unless you are using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output in enquiries.php.  I would recommend using json_encode.